# How to get keys as numbers in an object-as-a-map in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am using objects as maps in typescript:

```
const myMap: { [myKey: number]: string } = {};
myMap[42] = 'some string';
```

It works fine...

```
console.log(myMap[42]); // => 'some string'
```

...until I try to get the keys in the map

```
for (let key of Object.keys(myMap)) {
  // key is a string, not a number
}
```

I guess this is because Javascript actually stores the keys as strings internally, but **is there a way to get the keys as numbers?**

I guess I could use a `Map` but I'm a little wary of its performances. Also, I would lose some compatibility...

Comment: You could parse the string into an int : `parseInt` .

Comment: @madjaoue yes but not very elegant right?

Comment: yep, more like a patch than a real answer. But it's better than map for now. Although I am interested in the answer to this question.

Comment: You could use a sparse array, I suppose, but you might as well use a `Map` at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Well, iterating over the keys of an object is exactly what the [for-in loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) does. You just have to use `parseInt` on it:

```
for (let key in myMap) {
    if(myMap.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(parseInt(key)); // 42
        console.log(myMap[key]); // some string
    }
}
```

Comment: the `parseInt` is what I want to avoid :)

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. At least, OP could use `parseInt` in his code.

Comment: Is `Number(key)` possible or do you generally want to avoid a conversion call?

Answer (score 0):

> Actually, Javascript convert any Index Signature to string by
>   implicitly call toString().

You can check it by simply call:

```
console.log(myMap['42']); // => 'some string'
```

and it will still work. so whatever key you get from Object.keys() will be string.
If you still want to use it as number, you can do:

```
for (let key of Object.keys(myMap)) {
  console.log(typeof +key,'would be a number')
  console.log(typeof key, 'would be a string')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array, but then it puts `undefined` into every index not used. That makes iteration more challenging, and means it's impossible to purposefully add `undefined` to the "map" without losing it.

```js
const myMap = [];
myMap[42] = "some string";

// 42 commas, then "some string"
console.log(myMap.join(',')); 

// just "some string", but you lose the 42.
console.log(myMap.filter(e => typeof e !== "undefined").join(','));

// Something similar to Map.prototype.entries
for (let a of myMap.reduce((arr, cur, idx) => typeof cur !== "undefined" ? [...arr, [idx, cur]] : arr, [])) {
  console.log(a); // [ 42, "some string" ]
}

// Of course, a Map does this natively
const myTrueMap = new Map();
myTrueMap.set(42, "some string");

for (let e of myTrueMap.entries()) {
  console.log(e); // [ 42, "some string" ]
}
```

There are some polyfills for `Map` (e.g., https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-map, https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim), but YMMV.